# FlutterError: “Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe” on DrawerMenu?

Tags: flutter, drawer

I have a list like shown below. Since I uploaded the menu items, Language, going back part doesn't work. When I click on Flutter inspector, I get an error like the image below.

```
List<MenuItem> menuItems = [
    MenuItem(title: 'Contact' items: [
      MenuItem(title: 'WriteUs'),
      MenuItem(title: 'Call Center' items: [
        MenuItem(title: 'Call Call Center'),
        MenuItem(title: 'We will call you'),
      ]),
      MenuItem(title: 'WhatsApp'),
    ]),
    MenuItem(title: 'Language' items: [
      MenuItem(title: 'English'),
      MenuItem(title: 'Pусский'),
    ]),
    MenuItem(title:'Dealer'),
  ];
```

I only use the menu item in two places and their codes are here. When I looked from here,many answers were  that scaffold should be added.I tried but it didn't work

```
  renderContent() {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 22,
        right: 22,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          MaterialButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Cat.x, size: 19, color: HexColor('#2C2C2C')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ...renderMenuItems(context, menuItems),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

```
renderContentWithLogin() {
final topPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
return isLoading
    ? Container(
        color: Colors.white60,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
            radius: 30,
          ),
        ),
      )
    : Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 22, right: 22, top: topPadding, bottom: 22),
            color: HexColor('#FFA300'),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                MaterialButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 25),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Cat.x, size: 19, color: Colors.white),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  me != null ? '${me['firstName']} ${me['lastName']}' : '',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  customer != null ? customer['name'] + ' $countryCode': '',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ...renderCustomers(context),
              ],
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: HexColor('#D2D2D2')),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ...renderMenuItems(context, menuItems),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

}

And here is my Render mwnu item,

```
  renderMenuSubItems(BuildContext context) {
return selectedMenuItem.items.map(
  (item) => MaterialButton(
    onPressed: () {
      redirectItem(item);
    },
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Text(
          item.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

[image]

Comment: Anyone? No idea?